# How to get rid of confirmation for Windows 8 Bluetooth file transfers?

Tags: windows, windows-8, bluetooth, file-transfer

We have photo-kiosks running our own proprietary software for ordering pictures, and they are running Windows 8. The same software was previously running on Windows XP, and we could use Bluetooth file transfer so that a customer could send pictures from their phone/tablet which would appear on a folder on the computer that our software was watching. Now we have updated to Windows 8, and have run into a problem:
Every time Windows is about to receive incoming pictures, it shows a confirmation prompt. However, this confirmation prompt is shown in the background from our software, and it is never seen. What we need is for the computer to automatically accept incoming files via bluetooth. This was possible in previous version of Windows. How can we get rid of this prompt in Windows 8? (pairing devices is not a solution, as it would also involve prompts outside our own kiosk software)

Comment: Did you maybe find a solution? I've just finished Googling about this and your post on this very site is my last hope ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BlueSoleil 10 I was able to replace the Windows Bluetooth stack and get rid of the confirmation message. You can get BlueSoleil here: http://www.bluesoleil.com/ Unfortunately it is not free. Additionally it is not compatible with all Bluetooth USB dongles so I would recommend doing some research to ensure compatibility.